# How to look up for mutiple values - need to contain all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is a sales order info table, and users order different products.

I need to look up the users have order all three products (01,03,05)

I know I can easily user

where product in

to find users ordered one of the products, but I am stuck on how to look up for users ordered all three (and of course the products are more than just those three).

Help please, thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like following using `count distinct`

```
select UserId,count(distinct productid )
from TABLENAME
where productid in('01','02','03')
group by UserId
having count(distinct productid )=3
```

Comment: Where good point, in a list of three and have three orders.